# Using images within comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, images

I want to use an image within a *comment* (not within a *question*).

How does it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not possible. You can only post a link to a picture.

[Is it possible to add images to comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/is-it-possible-to-add-images-to-comments)

Answer (score 3):

You can paste the image first in the editor of an answer, then copy the link before saving the answer, discard the answer and insert the link to the image in the comment.

Comment: Nice trick, but I guess OP asks how to show (not to add link of) an image in comments. :)

Comment: You're probably right, so I guess there's no good answer to that question...